# Android Device Manager doesn't show emulated device on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, android, eclipse, emulation, android-studio

In the android AVD Manager (eclipse or android studio, doesn't matter) I can create a device, but when I want to start it the AVD manager loads and nothing happens.

Did anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: When downclicking a question, please help the person out and supply a reason.  This is especially important if this is someone's first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay after weeks, i finally find the answer to my problem:
Its from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712342/3477946

On Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with a NVidia graphics card I had to do the following:

Install the SDK and ADT plugin for Eclipse
Install 32-bit libraries:

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1`

Install OpenGL libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Install proprietary drivers for the graphics card:

```
System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers NVIDIA binary driver version 331.38
```

From Eclipse (>in my case android studio/<) , run the Android Virtual Device Manager and edit a device. Enable "Use Host GPU" & save.
It then worked.